# Magento2 - is there any class such as Mage_Shell_Abstract to extend?

Tags: magento2, shell, mage-shell

I mean, what's the right / best approach to write shell scripts, as the ones in Magento1 **/shell** folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento 2 uses the Symfony Console component. So you are not supposed to write single PHP scripts anymore, but commands that will be executed with `bin/magento`

**Documentation:** [How to add CLI commands](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/cli-cmds/cli-howto.html)

### Summary:

> Following is a summary of the process:
>
> 1. Create a Command class (the recommended location is `<your component root dir>/Console/Command`).
>
>    See `app/code/Magento/CommandExample/Console/Command` for examples.
> 2. Declare your Command class in `Magento\Framework\Console\CommandListInterface` using dependency injection (`<your component root dir>/etc/di.xml`).
>
> Clean the cache and compiled code directories:
>
> ```
> cd <your Magento install dir>/var
> rm -rf cache/* page_cache/* di/* generation/*
> ```